# Nginx deny not blocking dynamic URL's

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-location

I want to block access to my staging server site for everyone but my IP.
The problem is one of the pages has a dynamic URL and for some reason, I can still access this page using other IPs.

```
location / {

    satisfy  any;
    # allow my ip
    allow  1.2.3.4;
    # drop rest of the world
    deny    all;

    auth_basic            "Authentication Required";
    auth_basic_user_file  /etc/nginx/passwd;

    index  index.php index.html index.htm;

    # remove .php extension
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;

    sendfile   off;

    rewrite ^/color/(.*)$ /color.php?url=$1&name=&submitBtn=check;
}

location @rewrite {
      rewrite ^ $uri.php last;
}
```

The code above will let my IP access any page on the site without a password, but anybody else will be asked for a password before being granted access.

This works on all pages except the dynamic URL page. On the dynamic URL page the password shows up when accessing the page from different IP's but the page still loads, so the password is useless.

I've tried giving the dynamic URL it's own `location` block, and that works in blocking all IP's (except my IP) from accessing the dynamic page without first giving the password, but when I do this I get a `404` error when attempting to access the dynamic page from my IP address.

```
location / {
    ...
}

location ~ ^/color/(.*)$ {
    satisfy  any;
    # allow my ip
    allow  1.2.3.4;
    # drop rest of the world
    deny    all;

    auth_basic            "Authentication Required";
    auth_basic_user_file  /etc/nginx/passwd;
}
```

EDIT: I think the rewritten URL is the cause of the problem e.g `rewrite ^/color/(.*)$ /color.php?url=$1&name=&submitBtn=check;`, because I can also navigate to `mysite.com/color` and this also loads for other IP's even though the browser password field displays.

Comment: If you are trying to block all access - the `allow/deny` rules should be in the `server` block - and not just one `location` block.

Comment: @Richard Smith, Thanks, thats fixed it. I just added the `allow/deny, auth basic and satisfy` rules into the `server` block and removed them from the `location` block. Can't believe I didn't think of that :)